# Set data for attribute in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a managed bean page and a variable : `idCate`

```
public int idCate;

public int getIdCate() {
    return idCate;
}

public void setIdCate(int idCate) {
    this.idCate = idCate;
}
```

and I have an `xhtml` page:

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{categoriesBean.allcate}" var="Cate">
    <ul class="leftm">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="tit">
                <h:outputText value="#{Cate.categoryname}" />
            </a>
        </li>                         
        <!-- I want set value for idCate. ex:  categoriesBean.idCate = 1 -->
        <ui:repeat value="#{categoriesBean.listSubcate}" var="subCate">
            <li><a href="#">- #{subCate.categoryname}</a></li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
</ui:repeat>
```

How can I set value to idCate variable. I want using idCate variable in my bean page.

Comment: You want setting the idCate when clicking on the link?!

Comment: no, i only want set idCate to using in my bean. I want show categories parrent and categories in my index page. And i want set idCate to get id of categories parrent. Sorry for my english

Comment: If I understand, you want idCate to get listSubcate according to it?

Comment: yes. This is my idea. Thanks.

Comment: You should change `public int idCate;` for `private int idCate;` since you have getter/setter :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion in the comments, there is two ways

**1. You could do some sort of lazy loading :**

**View :**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{categoriesBean.getListSubcate(Cate)}" var="subCate">
    <li><a href="#">- #{subCate.categoryname}</a></li>
</ui:repeat>
```

**Bean :**

```
public List<SubCate> getListSubcate(Cate cate)
{
    return // Your business logic from cate.getIdCate() ...
}
```

**2. Or you can prepare the entire list before :**

**View :**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{Cate.subCates}" var="subCate">
    <li><a href="#">- #{subCate.categoryname}</a></li>
</ui:repeat>
```

**Bean :**

```
// Add a list of subCates inside your Category class
public class Cate
{
    private List<SubCate> subCates;

    public void setSubCates(List<SubCate> subCates)
    {
        this.subCates = subCates;
    }

    public List<SubCate> getSubCates()
    {
        return this.subCates;
    }
}
```

And you should initialize sub-categories right after or at the same time you do for categories. I strongly suggest this second way since your getter will be called more than once so you will not recreate data everytime. All data must be initialized in bean constructor or in a `@PostConstruct` method.

```
public CategoriesBean
{
    private List<Cate> allCate;

    public CategoriesBean()
    {
        // Initialize allCate here
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        // Or here
    }

    public List<Cate> getAllCate()
    {
        // Or here
        if(allCate == null)
        {
            this.allCate = ...
        }

        return this.allCate;
    }
}
```